# customer user name displayed on header bar when user logged out by session time automatically

Tags: magento2, customer, login, session

I am building the magento 2.4 website
By the way I am facing with below customer login issue

"I had logged into the website with customer account
I spent some times and I visited the site by the way username is displaying and no logout button, login button is displaying - I am pretty sure that this user account is logged out automatically by session

Why is this user account name displaying still?

I had tried to purge all history and cookie of the chrome browser in chrome browser clear section

And I had tried to do
OK this account name is appeared

Anyway I don't know why this account user name is displaying always before history of the chrome browser is cleared

---

my actions

step 1:

[image]

step 2:
I had logged into the site

[image]

step 3:
After 10 min I refresh the browser

[image]

step 4:
clear all data in chrome browser

[image]

step 5:

[image]

How can I set or fix this issue

Hope to help for this issue

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Its magento cache issue not browser cache issue.

please disable cache once and check your functionality. if it works then please remove that section from cache.

Its in header so I guess your site will be not cachable after fix that issue but still you wanna fix issue for now please use below code in xml

> <block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" **cacheable="false"** />

mark as solution if works for you